# Android: App/Activity loses connection to ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Good Morning All,

I am having trouble with my Activity's ActionBar keeping proper functionality after it is left for a period of time.  Basically I have different ActionBar views set up dependant on which page in a ViewPager that I'm on.  The middle page of 3 implements ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST with a list that is used to filter the content of the ListView on that page.  On the other two pages this list is not shown.  My code for handling this:

```
  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends MyPagerAdapter  {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment;
        if(i==0){

            ActionBar bar = MyApp.this.getActionBar();
             bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD); 
            fragment   = page1;

        }else if(i==1){
             fragment =  page2;

        }else{
            fragment   =  page3;                        
        }
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }


@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {


    if(position== 1  && menuSearch != null){     

            menuSearch.setVisible(true);       
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);   


    }else{   
        if(menuSearch != null){
            menuSearch.setVisible(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);    
        }
    }

    currentPage = position;

}

public int getCurrentPage() {

    return currentPage;
}
```

I am currently able to force the failure for testing by starting a new activity, which I can then force close, and when I come back to this main activity the ActionBars drop down menu is shown on every page.  The menu also loses connection to the filtering properties it performed in 2nd page.

UPDATE 1:

I now believe that my problem lies with a disconnect between my ViewPager, ActionBar and the Fragments they control.  I added the following code to the onNavigationItemSelected portion of my Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {

        Log.i(TAG,"Fragment ID:" + String.valueOf(fragment.getId()));
    if(fragment.isAdded()){
        Log.i(TAG,"fragment.isAdded");
             }
```

When I first run the app these Logs return the following:

**Fragment ID: 2131492869
fragment.isAdded**

However, after I force a crash or leave the app and come back later, the Logs return

**Fragment ID: 0**

The fragment.isAdded is false at this point, but I'm not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone give me insight about why this may be happening? Should I be saving the actionbar state somehow in onPause and then restoring in onResume?

Yes, this is happening becuase you not save the last index ,

so basically what you need to do is

in `onResume`

set the viewPager current index like this : `viewPager.setCurrentItem(lastFragmentIndex);`

I think you need to save your fragments in `onSaveInstanceState` and restore them in `onRestoreInstanceState`  like this:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.putFragment(outState, 1, fragment1);
            fm.putFragment(outState, 2, fragment2);
}
```

and restore

```
 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();    
            fragment1 = (Fragment) fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState, 1);
}
```

Comment: That didn't fix the issue.  I set lastFragmentIndex as an int in the onPause() method.  Was that the intent?

Comment: yes, that was the intent, am not sure you doing right try to set to specific index like "1"  in onresume and make sure every time  onresume called you changed to index 1

Comment: Ok,  with some minor modification I am able to get this working.  However,  the drop down in my actionbar still loses it's link to the content provider to which it's attached.  I'm confused because there is also a search button that remains working with the content provider in the same actionbar.

Comment: Updated the question above with new information.  Your help is appreciated.